# @SpringBootTest causes @PostConstruct to be called twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

With Spring Boot of version 1.4 sone test annotations where deprecated "in favor of {@link SpringBootTest}".

Hovewer simply replacing deprecated annotations with new one, causes one strange side affect for me, @PostConstruct is called twice.

So lets assume that it was before

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationTestContext.class})
@IntegrationTest
@Transactional
public class EmployeesControllerSpringTest {

@Inject
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

@Inject
private VenueRepository venueRepository;

@Inject
private TestUtilDummyObjects dummyObjects;

@Inject
private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

@Inject
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Inject
private ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() {

    EmployeesController sut = new EmployeesController(employeeRepository);

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(sut)
            .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter)
            .build();
}
```

So, replasing deprecated annottions with the following

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ApplicationTestContext.class})
@Transactional
```

causes @PostConstruct to be called twice.

Maybe someone can suggest, what am I doing wrong?

Please see ApplicationTestContext.class below:

```
//@TestConfiguration
//@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type =    FilterType.REGEX,
    pattern = "somepath.*")})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class,   MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ApplicationProperties.class, LiquibaseProperties.class})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = false)
public class ApplicationTestContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new LocalDateConverter(Constants.DATE_FORMAT));
    registry.addConverter(new LocalDateTimeConverter(Constants.DATE_TIME_FORMAT));
}
```

}

**UPDATE**

Following @bhantol sugestion (get rid of all redundand annotations), I've tried to run official sample https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/.

Simply downloading sources and changing @Before to @PostConstruct still causing it to be called twice.

code from the sample is below:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HelloControllerIT {

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

private URL base;

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate template;

//@Before
@PostConstruct
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    this.base = new URL("http://localhost:" + port + "/");
    System.out.println("");
}

@Test
public void getHello() throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity(base.toString(),
            String.class);
    assertThat(response.getBody(), equalTo("Greetings from Spring Boot!"));
}
}
```

Not sure, but seems like a potential bug.

Comment: Do you have test and main source/classpath separated i.e. using maven/gradle ? One rare possibility is that the test classes might have come under scan as main source and it is happening again in the test context.

Comment: Maven is utilized. Test classes are separate to the main source files. In any case it is strange that SpringApplicationConfiguration does not cause such issue, but SpringBootTest does.

Comment: Is your `postConstruct` method being called twice on the same instance, or are two instances being created? Also why are you using `@PostConstruct` rather than `@Before` which is more conventional in a test class.

Comment: `@EnableWebMvc`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan` are implicit/redeudant in the `@SpringBootApplication`. So a `@SpringBootTest` being equivalent to the `@SpringBootApplication` might cause redundant functions causing the bean lifecyle called more than 1 times. Try getting rid of those redundant Annotations.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thank you for reply. The same instance. I've also notices that Before works just fine for me, but I do not really see any reason in constructng mockMvc for each test. It is just like a workaround for right now. Also, please see update.

Comment: @bhantol. Thank you for help. I've tried what you've sugested. Please see initial issue update.

Comment: Any possibility that your pom/project pulls CDI enabler jars that enables CDI causing @PostConstruct ?